# Split string between less and greater than

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I need to split this kind of strings to separate the email between less and greater than **< >**. Im trying with the next `regex` and `preg_split`, but I does not works.

```
"email1@domain.com" <email1@domain.com>
News <news@e.domain.com>
Some Stuff <email-noreply@somestuff.com>
```

The expected result will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "email1@domain.com"
    [1] => email@email.com
)
Array
(
    [0] => News
    [1] => news@e.domain.com
)
Array
(
    [0] => Some Stuff
    [1] => email-noreply@somestuff.com
)
```

Code that I am using now:

```php
foreach ($emails as $email)
{
   $pattern = '/<(.*?)>/';
   $result = preg_split($pattern, $email);
   print_r($result);
}
```

Comment: what output you want to have? looks like the split is working.

Comment: the output that i want to have is what i typed after **The expected result will be:**. Now, the split is not working because I don't get anything splitter. I always have the same string that original. That is what I want to get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use some of the flags available for [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split): `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` *and* `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`.

```
$emails = array('"email1@domain.com" <email1@domain.com>', 'News <news@e.domain.com>', 'Some Stuff <email-noreply@somestuff.com>');

foreach ($emails as $email)
{
    $pattern = '/<(.*?)>/';
    $result = preg_split($pattern, $email, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    print_r($result);
}
```

This outputs what you expect:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "email1@domain.com" 
    [1] => email1@domain.com
)
Array
(
    [0] => News 
    [1] => news@e.domain.com
)
Array
(
    [0] => Some Stuff 
    [1] => email-noreply@somestuff.com
)
```

Comment: What would be the `$pattern` to use?

Comment: The same as you already have. I'll edit the answer for the shake of clarity.

Comment: Not working... I am getting always the original string, for example `array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(57) ""email1@domain.com" <email1@domain.com>"
}`

Comment: Works fine on my end. Did you use the code "as is"? Try to copy and paste, just to be sure.

Comment: You are right, that is working. But not con my array. I will try to guess why, I suppose that it would be a stupid thing. Thanks you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Splitting on something removes the delimiter (i.e. everything the regex matches). You probably want to split on

```
\s*<|>
```

instead. Or you can use `preg_match` with the regex

```
^(.*?)\s*<([^>]+)>
```

and use the first and second capturing groups.

Comment: I am getting `preg_match(): Unknown modifier '>'` with the second option and `preg_split(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash` with the first.

Comment: I gave you a regex, you need to add delimiters to use them with the PCRE functions in PHP. And maybe escape things depending on the strings you use. So it should probably be `'/^(.*?)\s*<([^>]+)>/'` for use there.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job. [click here for Codepad link](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tGzPhX)

```
$header = '"email1@domain.com" <email1@domain.com>
News <news@e.domain.com>
Some Stuff <email-noreply@somestuff.com>';

$result = array();
preg_match_all('!(.*?)\s+<\s*(.*?)\s*>!', $header, $result);

$formatted = array();
for ($i=0; $i<count($result[0]); $i++) {
  $formatted[] = array(
    'name' => $result[1][$i],
    'email' => $result[2][$i],
  );
}
print_r($formatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("/<(.*?)>/", $string, $result_array);
print_r($result_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$email='"email1@domain.com" <email1@domain.com>
News <news@e.domain.com>
Some Stuff <email-noreply@somestuff.com>';
$pattern = '![^\>\<]+!';
preg_match_all($pattern, $email,$match);
print_r($match);
```

Ouput:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
[0] => "email1@domain.com" 
[1] => email1@domain.com 
[2] => News 
[3] => news@e.domain.com 
[4] => Some Stuff 
[5] => email-noreply@somestuff.com ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also split by <, and get rid of ">" in $result

```
  $pattern = '/</';
  $result = preg_split($pattern, $email);
  $result = preg_replace("/>/", "", $result);
```